# JAVA: no such file or directory (libjli.so)

Tags: raspbian, ssh, software-installation, java, jessie-lite

OK. Let me start. I am busy making a musical floppy player, connected everything up to my Raspberry Pi, and wrote a Java program to control it. I used OpenJDK 7 on Raspbian Jessie Lite. Then I took a break from the Pi, and continued the program on my workstation. When I loaded it onto the Pi, it froze. Turns out OpenJDK doesn't like MIDI sequencers. So I uninstalled OpenJDK, and went through a hard time trying t oinstall the Oracle JDK. I tried:

- PPA's (webupd8): turns out there isn't a version for jessie
- i586, x64 JDK's: I was too stupid

Finally I arrived at the Oracle Java SE 7 JDK for ARM. Downloaded tar.gz, scp'ed to Pi, extracted with `tar` to `/usr/lib/jvm`. Used (while in root)

```
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/java" 1
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/javac" 1
chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
```

and all went perfectly. Then I tried `java -version` and got:

```
java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked, there is definitely a `libjli.so` in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60/lib/arm/jli` and `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60/jre/lib/arm/jli`

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the user you are running your program as have the libjli,so file directory in its path?

Comment: I didn't run my program yet, I only tried `java -version`. What path are you talking about? Sorry, I am still learning all the linux stuff

Comment: who did you run java version as (pi)?

Comment: I did it in root and pi, all the same

Comment: if the path for the user you ran java version as does not have that file in its path it won't gind it

Comment: how do i add it to the path or check if it is there?

Comment: echo $PATH will show your path a quick google search will show you how to edit the .bashrc file to set the path

Comment: I ran `echo $PATH` and got `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`. Should libjli.so be in one of those directories? Or the path to libjli.so in some text document?EDIT: that was root. under pi it is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

Comment: try adding this /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60/jre/lib/arm/jli or this /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60/lib/arm/jli to your path

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ PATH=$PATH:~/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60/jre/lib/arm/jli
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60/jre/lib/arm/jli
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ java -version
java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16656/problem-to-launch-java-at-debian-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libjli or https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=no%20such%20file%20or%20directory%20libjli.so&es_th=1

Answer (score 2):

Got it working. Turns out some weird stuff was happening with the permissions, so I installed Java 8 and it worked fine. Thanks Steve Robillard!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30165)